# INSERT query of SQLite shows 0 values

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am makeing a small project in flask/python in which I have got just ONE DATABASE, which has ONE table and ONE column init.
BUT my DATABASE is giving an ERROR
whenever I am checking my database by firing '''python dbase.py''' in cmd.
It gives an ERROR which says...

""File "dbase.py", line 19, in 
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO tdaba (input) VALUES (?)", daba)
  sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 3 supplied."""

I will be using this database to make online entry of TEXT into the column 'input' and for that I need the INSERT query.

My DATABASE name is "daba" and it is store in the file named "dbase.py"
AND the code it has is::

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

daba = (
    ('1st mssg'),
    ('my 2nd mssg'),
    ('3rd msg, How r U ?')
)


con = lite.connect('daba.db')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tdaba")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tdaba(input TEXT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tdaba (input) VALUES (?)", daba)
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is "daba". It is tuple of strings instead of tuple of tuples

```
In [1]: daba = (
....:     ('1st mssg'),
....:     ('my 2nd mssg'),
....:     ('3rd msg, How r U ?')
....: )
In [2]: daba
Out[2]: ('1st mssg', 'my 2nd mssg', '3rd msg, How r U ?')
```

Fixing - adding comma after each string (needed for tuples with one element).

```
daba = (
   ('1st mssg',),
   ('my 2nd mssg',),
   ('3rd msg, How r U ?',)
)
```

Second problem - execute method. You should use executemany. Check the [samples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO tdaba (input) VALUES (?)", daba)
```